# What is the date format for the "since" annotation in javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I've tried googling this but didn't find a complete answer to this question:

Can I set the date format for the @since annotation in javadoc? Or how do I see what format is set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The **@since** tag should be used to define which version you added
>   the method, class, etc. This is your hint to other developers that
>   they should only expect the method when they run against a particular
>   version of the package. I would consider these uber-important parts of
>   the documentation if you're shipping your code as a library intended
>   for someone else to use.

```
/**
 * @author    Firstname Lastname <address @ example.com>
 * @version   1.6        (current version number of program)
 * @since     1.5        (the version of the package this class was first added to)
 */
```

For more information visit:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

[javadoc: @version and @since](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578363/javadoc-version-and-since)

Comment: thanks, i was confused since on the wiki, the example given was a date-like version of a package!

Comment: Wikipedia is not a normative reference. Use the reference material provided.

Answer (score 3):

The tag **@since** is not used to specify date rather it is used to provide information about the last version information

```
/**    
* @since 1.7
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

@since 1.1

since is followed by a number which indicates some sort of version ID.
Any format would do but N.N format is preferred

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the string for @since has no real syntax, I write mine as @since 2020.09.22 which appears to be either a version or a date.

Answer (score 1):

`@since` annotation is used to describe when the functionality first existed, it's version number.

Answer (score 1):

As I know `@Since` is use to indicate version which start some implementation.

```
@Since 1.0  // meaning is this method start from version 1.0
```