# Why %I% is not showing my version JavaDoc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

On Android Studio Im trying to get the version incrementally while I develop my code, but for some reason doing this

```
/**
 * This is an example class
 * @author  Todd Williams
 * @version %I%
 * @since 1.0
 */
```

is showing me this

[image]

Any idea why ?

Comment: This macro is handled by your version control system, not by the IDE, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/578387/104891. Make sure the VCS you are using is configured to replace `%I%` with the actual version when you checkout the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer